# Solution of $y(3y+10x^2)dx-2x(y+3x^2)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

My attempt:
I tried to find the Integrating Factor but couldn't find it by the standard methods. Also this is a non-linear differential equation which is non-homogeneous. I couldn't find any substitution as well which would simplify the equation.

$y(3y+10x^2)dx-2x(y+3x^2)dy=0$

$M= y(3y+10x^2) \,\, and \,\,N=2x(y+3x^2) $

$\therefore \, \dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}=6y+10x^2 \,\,\,\, and\,\,\,\, \dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-2y-18x^2 $

How do I proceed from here to find the Integrating Factor?

Answer (score 1):

$$y(3y+10x^2)2xdx-4x^2(y+3x^2)dy=0$$
$X=x^2$
$$y(3y+10X)dX-4X(y+3X)dy=0$$
HINT : Now, the equation is homogeneous.

Comment: Hey thanks. But I wanted to ask is there a general way to solve these type of equations? Cause it's not possible to guess the substitution every time

Comment: In the general case it is arduous to find an integration factor $\mu(x,y)$ because $\mu$ is solution of a first order linear PDE which is quite as difficult to solve than the original ODE. Of course in case of problems for students, the ODE is chosen to be easily solvable. Often an integrating factor can be seen by inspection. More difficult, one look for particular forms of integrating factor : $x$-dependant, $y$-dependant, $(xy)$-dependant,... See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactFirst-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html . These approach is sufficient to solve most of the textbook cases.

Comment: Of course, before starting any calculus, by inspection try to simplify the ODE. This is the most important advice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice